# Out of place image in outlook 07/10

Tags: html, css

I have just designed my first html eshot and tested it on different email clients using Mailchimps inbox inspector. Its fine across all clients as far as I can see except for Outlook 2007 & 2010. The image on the left moves out of place quite a bit. Outlook 2003 and all others are fine, its just 2007 & 2010 causing the problem.

[Weblink (how it should look)](http://smashingpack.com/eshot/eshottest.html)

Outlook 2007 & 2010 (how it shouldn't look):

[image: http://smashingpack.com/eshot/outlook/2007.jpg]

Does anybody know whats wrong? I'v tried all sorts and it nothing is working, its driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm looking at your two samples side-by-side and you're going to have to do a much better job explaining the various differences... it's not obvious.  Also, post your code, otherwise, what would you expect us to do?  Also, it's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you if this is some kind of weird MailChimp previewing error.

Answer (score 0):

My estimation, looking at your code, is `colspan` is causing an issue.  In my experience with coding e-mails, `colspan` and `rowspan` should be avoided.  If you need to change the number of columns, close the table and start a new table.  It's a lot of extra markup, but that's the deal with coding emails.

Coding e-mails is very, very challenging.  There's many articles on the challenges with the various e-mail clients and their quirks - not to mention GMail, AOL, Yahoo!, etc.

I would suggest starting here:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
Their chart gives you a quick overview of the compatibility of various css selectors, etc. with the email clients out there.

Then, you need to learn some of the strange things that happen, such as the margin that GMail adds to images.  (Add `display:block;` to the images: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3132/how-to-stop-gmail-from-adding-a-margin-to-your-images/)

A tool that I have begun to use is [Email On Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/), which lets you preview the e-mails in a WIDE variety of email clients.